# How presentViewController works when called on viewController or on NavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

**What are the pros and cons of below two approaches of presenting View Controller ? What's the difference ?**

```
 UIViewController *abcVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abcVC"];

 [self presentViewController:abcVC];
```

**or**

```
 UIViewController *abcVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abcVC"];
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:abcVC];
```

Comment: You want use presentViewcontroller  with navigationController?

Comment: and use [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; because  your method are deprecated in latest ios version

Comment: if my viewcontroller is on navigationcontroller stack, then what will be the difference between presenting viewcontroller on self or on self.navigationcontroller ?

Comment: There is no difference but when you are presenting any view controller modally on another view controller which is embedded in navigation controller . but you can not use self.navigationController if view controller is not embedded in navigation controller

Comment: Another difference is that if you present using your navigation controller, the presented controller doesn't know who really presented it.  That usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The first method, you mention will work only when the parent view controller is not having the navigation controller,

The second method you mention will work only when the parent view controller is the navigation controller,

but both method will present the view controller,

Answer (score 0):

Correction here `[self presentViewController:abcVC];` is deprecated method and new one is
   `[self presentViewController:abcVC animated:YES completion:nil];`.
Both above mentioned will do same thing and you don't need to use `self.navigationController` to present a controller modally.
[UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) manage a stack of controllers and thats why we use it for push and pop purpose.Use UINavigationController if you need to push a controller and you want a native back button to switch back to previous controller.
i hope this will help you.